# next and previous buttons don't work

Tags: javascript, button

This code is for making a calendar. When I click the next button nothing happens. I would want that when I click the next button the page would load the second month and the same goes for the previous button.

```js
var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var days =  [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
var body = document.body;
var counter = 0;

function calendar(){
  for(var i = 1; i<=days[counter]; i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var calendar1 = document.createTextNode(i);
    div.appendChild(calendar1);
    body.appendChild(div);
  } 
}

function next(){
  counter++;
}

function previous(){
  counter--;
}
calendar(0);
```

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}
div{
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="next()">Next</button>
<button onclick="previous()">Previous</button>
```

Comment: You might need to clear the current calendar, then call `calendar(counter)`. There might be other work to do also, and much more efficient ways to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to redraw your calendar after updating `counter`.

Then, your `next` and `previous` function should call `calendar`.

But note `calendar` should clear current calendar before displaying the updated calendar.

```js
var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
    wraper = document.getElementById('calendar'),
    counter = 0;
function calendar(){
  wraper.innerHTML = ''; // Clear current calendar
  for(var i = 1; i<=days[counter]; i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var calendar1 = document.createTextNode(i);
    div.appendChild(calendar1);
    wraper.appendChild(div);
  } 
}
document.getElementById('next').onclick = function next(){
  ++counter;
  calendar()
};
document.getElementById('prev').onclick = function previous(){
  --counter;
  calendar()
};
calendar();
```

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}
#calendar > div{
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="next">Next</button>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```